# Zipped data getting loss during copying from FTP to windows

Tags: perl

I am trying to copy some zipped file from FTP to my local system (Windows). The transfer mode is `default mode (ASCII)`. File is getting copied, I am not getting any problem during transfer.
The problem is that the size of file on FTP to the one which is copied on my local system is different.

```
FTP_file_size -> 12,812,085
Copied_file_size->12,551
```

Above files should be the same.

Now I am not able to figure it out what is wrong going with transfer.

For script which i am using please refer :

[Why am I getting "File not found" errors with this Perl script using Net::FTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348978/why-am-i-getting-file-not-found-errors-with-this-perl-script-using-netftp)

Comment: I tried with binary mode also but same thing is happening. I had added $ftp->binary; in my code at just above the $ftp->get("$temp");

Comment: It seems Net::FTP module does not support 

MODE->Specifies transfer mode (stream, block or compressed) for file to be transferred.

Comment: One thing you can try is compare the original and transferred files in a hex viewer. Also, could you check what size the files are in bytes? 12,812,085 is roughly 12551 kilobytes so it's not easy to see how big a difference there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the binary (type "I") mode to transfer. Otherwise the FTP client translates line-ending characters to the local convention (on Windows: CR-LF) which would corrupt the ZIP format.

Comment: @ Joni Salonen, Actually when i extracting the files it says file is corrupt:( n as u suggested me to use $ftp->binary(type "I") instead of $ftp->binary; I had tried it but now after double clicking on the script it displays for a sec and then disappear.

Comment: Do we have any other module that supports FTP file transfer along with full support of windows functionality

Comment: @user1202644 It does fully support Windows, that's the problem. You have to use binary format because ZIP is a binary format.

Comment: @ Brad Gilbert as i mentioned dear i have tried it but nothing is happening. i don't know  what to do now :(

Comment: Any other way for using binary mode i mean i have tried above two but those are not working for me .anyways thanks for @Joni Salonen for suggestion

Comment: From the source code (https://metacpan.org/source/GBARR/libnet-1.22/Net/FTP.pm) I see there are two ways of setting the transfer type to binary: `$ftp->binary` and `$ftp->type("I")`. If none of those work for you the problem must be something else. 1. Are the files the same size in bytes? 2. Are you sure the original file is not corrupt? 3. Are you using the latest version of `Net::FTP`?